# Submitting ASP.NET form with javascript - textbox value not submitted

Tags: javascript, asp.net, form-submit

I have a dynamic form written in ASP (C#). In the page_load I am adding the text box I want to submit along other objects.

The form is submitted with a  tag through javascript.

```
    HyperLink btnBuy = new HyperLink();       
    btnBuy.CssClass = "btnLinkBuy btnLinkCheckoutGreen";
    btnBuy.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "GreenMouseOver()");
    btnBuy.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "GreenMouseOut()");
    btnBuy.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:postback()");
    btnBuy.NavigateUrl = "#";
    pnlVisaIcons.Controls.Add(btnBuy);
```

and the script is

```
function postback() {
            document.getElementById("checkoutForm").submit();
}
```

in the page_load event I am checking if IsPostBack and if so I call the function which handles the data submitted. However when I am checking the controllers they are empty. Like the post back deleted all the data

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add dynamic controls on `PreInit`, also you have to add the dynamic control(s) on each postback.

[ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)

Comment: I forgot to say: my form id is **"checkoutForm"**. When I am clicking my button (href with onclick that fires the submit action) in debug mode I get to the Page_Load event handler and the form controls have no value. This is after I dynamically loaded all the controls to the page